How to connect glue job and RDS without catalog
I've been trying a lot to find a solution to establish connection between glue job and RDS postgresql but all the solutions are using glue catalog which I don't want to use.
I only want to establish a connection and send some data from glue job (spark script) to my RDS database. I have already created the tables in my RDS database now I want to just send the data to it. How should I approach it?
Also I found some articles/videos to do this using jdbc but none of them are using glue job script. Please help me out.

If you don't wish to use the Glue Catalog or the Glue connectors for any reason, you can just using python libraries like psycopg2 like in any vanilla python script. just make sure that you specified psycopg2-binary in the following parameter of the job config --additional-python-modules:
import psycopg2

# Connection details
host = "your_rds_host"
database = "your_database_name"
user = "your_username"
password = "your_password"
port = "5432"  # Default PostgreSQL port

# Query to execute
query = """
SELECT * FROM your_table LIMIT 10;
"""

# Connect to the RDS instance
with psycopg2.connect(
    host=host,
    database=database,
    user=user,
    password=password,
    port=port,
) as conn:
    # Create a cursor
    with conn.cursor() as cur:
        # Execute the query
        cur.execute(query)

        # Fetch
        results = cur.fetchall()


would I have to add some connections as well in glue job details?

@Bee Not explicitly no, but you need to make sure that the security settings of your rds allow queries from the subnet CiDR you are using in your glue job
